# Is possible to group by the next register in R with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for a way to group this kind of data:

```
6160407 1853162 cin1    csa1
6203165 1904030 cin1    csa1
8453347 6050699 cin1    csa1
8507125 5996661 cin1    csa1
```

I want to plot this with `geom_point()` but adding a line indicating a relationship between the first register '6160407' and '6203165' in x-axis and the same with its correspondent '1853162' and '1904030' in y-axis. Could it be possible with group?

The basic plot is:

```
ggplot(data, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_point(aes(colour=V4))
```

I know that a `geom_line()` is missing to group by this way. Have you some ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Some data.frame info:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(2918848L, 3020406L, 3012485L, 3059964L, 
6118180L, 6144325L, 2672731L, 2726260L, 6169400L, 6239623L, 3225659L, 
3243523L, 2921684L, 2952518L, 6077605L, 6094096L, 2871288L, 2895608L, 
2920133L, 2929167L, 2829837L, 2837542L, 5593511L, 5597323L, 5594916L, 
5597195L, 5594925L, 5601716L, 6158310L, 6165279L), V2 = c(2842270L, 
2739302L, 2746640L, 2683527L, 1018440L, 1070436L, 3159605L, 3082481L, 
937756L, 992470L, 106256L, 89087L, 620180L, 651582L, 73636L, 
42430L, 3124288L, 3099294L, 2854976L, 2838157L, 3126301L, 3112938L, 
2929012L, 2932231L, 554507L, 552825L, 567380L, 563320L, 989274L, 
1011135L), V3 = structure(c(190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 
190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 
190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 
190L, 190L), .Label = c("cin1", "cin10", "cin102", "cin1049", 
"cin107", "cin108", "cin109", "cin11", "cin111", "cin113", "cin116", 
"cin117", "cin118", "cin119", "cin12", "cin120", "cin121", "cin122", 
"cin123", "cin126", "cin128", "cin129", "cin13", "cin131", "cin133", 
"cin135", "cin136", "cin137", "cin138", "cin14", "cin142", "cin143", 
"cin148", "cin149", "cin15", "cin150", "cin152", "cin153", "cin154", 
"cin155", "cin16", "cin160", "cin161", "cin165", "cin169", "cin17", 
"cin170", "cin171", "cin172", "cin173", "cin174", "cin175", "cin176", 
"cin177", "cin179", "cin18", "cin187", "cin188", "cin189", "cin19", 
"cin190", "cin192", "cin193", "cin195", "cin197", "cin198", "cin2", 
"cin20", "cin203", "cin204", "cin209", "cin21", "cin212", "cin216", 
"cin218", "cin22", "cin223", "cin226", "cin23", "cin232", "cin233", 
"cin234", "cin237", "cin24", "cin244", "cin246", "cin248", "cin25", 
"cin254", "cin26", "cin263", "cin267", "cin27", "cin271", "cin272", 
"cin279", "cin28", "cin280", "cin283", "cin285", "cin29", "cin294", 
"cin298", "cin299", "cin3", "cin30", "cin304", "cin305", "cin307", 
"cin31", "cin310", "cin32", "cin320", "cin33", "cin331", "cin34", 
"cin35", "cin358", "cin36", "cin361", "cin364", "cin37", "cin370", 
"cin38", "cin381", "cin387", "cin389", "cin39", "cin396", "cin4", 
"cin40", "cin403", "cin408", "cin41", "cin42", "cin421", "cin429", 
"cin43", "cin44", "cin441", "cin444", "cin45", "cin453", "cin46", 
"cin467", "cin47", "cin475", "cin48", "cin49", "cin5", "cin50", 
"cin51", "cin513", "cin52", "cin527", "cin529", "cin53", "cin537", 
"cin54", "cin547", "cin55", "cin56", "cin57", "cin58", "cin581", 
"cin586", "cin59", "cin6", "cin60", "cin619", "cin62", "cin63", 
"cin64", "cin65", "cin66", "cin67", "cin68", "cin682", "cin69", 
"cin7", "cin70", "cin71", "cin73", "cin737", "cin75", "cin76", 
"cin77", "cin78", "cin79", "cin8", "cin82", "cin83", "cin832", 
"cin833", "cin85", "cin86", "cin87", "cin88", "cin881", "cin9", 
"cin90", "cin92", "cin93", "cin94", "cin95", "cin96", "cin99"
), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 
163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 
163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 
163L, 163L, 163L, 163L), .Label = c("csa1", "csa10", "csa100", 
"csa101", "csa102", "csa103", "csa104", "csa105", "csa106", "csa107", 
"csa108", "csa109", "csa11", "csa110", "csa112", "csa113", "csa114", 
"csa115", "csa116", "csa117", "csa118", "csa119", "csa12", "csa120", 
"csa121", "csa122", "csa123", "csa125", "csa126", "csa127", "csa128", 
"csa129", "csa13", "csa130", "csa131", "csa132", "csa133", "csa134", 
"csa135", "csa136", "csa137", "csa138", "csa139", "csa14", "csa140", 
"csa141", "csa143", "csa144", "csa145", "csa146", "csa147", "csa148", 
"csa149", "csa15", "csa150", "csa151", "csa152", "csa153", "csa154", 
"csa156", "csa158", "csa16", "csa160", "csa163", "csa164", "csa166", 
"csa168", "csa17", "csa170", "csa172", "csa173", "csa176", "csa179", 
"csa18", "csa185", "csa186", "csa189", "csa19", "csa192", "csa194", 
"csa195", "csa197", "csa199", "csa2", "csa20", "csa200", "csa203", 
"csa205", "csa206", "csa21", "csa210", "csa211", "csa214", "csa22", 
"csa220", "csa229", "csa23", "csa230", "csa24", "csa25", "csa253", 
"csa258", "csa26", "csa261", "csa267", "csa27", "csa270", "csa28", 
"csa288", "csa29", "csa294", "csa3", "csa30", "csa301", "csa304", 
"csa307", "csa308", "csa31", "csa32", "csa325", "csa329", "csa33", 
"csa337", "csa34", "csa35", "csa36", "csa37", "csa38", "csa39", 
"csa4", "csa40", "csa41", "csa42", "csa43", "csa44", "csa45", 
"csa46", "csa47", "csa48", "csa49", "csa5", "csa50", "csa51", 
"csa52", "csa53", "csa54", "csa55", "csa56", "csa57", "csa58", 
"csa59", "csa6", "csa60", "csa61", "csa62", "csa63", "csa64", 
"csa65", "csa66", "csa67", "csa68", "csa69", "csa7", "csa70", 
"csa71", "csa72", "csa73", "csa74", "csa75", "csa76", "csa77", 
"csa78", "csa79", "csa8", "csa80", "csa81", "csa82", "csa83", 
"csa84", "csa85", "csa86", "csa87", "csa88", "csa89", "csa9", 
"csa90", "csa91", "csa92", "csa93", "csa94", "csa95", "csa96", 
"csa97", "csa98", "csa99"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4"), row.names = 199181:199210, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it 'manually' with `geom_segment`, is this what you're looking for?

```
ggplot(data, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_point(aes(colour=V4)) + 
   geom_segment(aes(x=6160407, xend=6203165, y=1853162, yend=1904030, colour=V4)) + 
   geom_segment(aes(x=8453347, xend=8507125, y=6050699, yend=5996661, colour=V4))
```

[image: plot]

Trying to do it in a more generic way may require more of your data.frame and/or sepcifying your problem. Also, defining `colnames` on data will be easier to handle and would produce nicely labelled plots.

Comment: It is precisely the think that I want to do, but wit almost 1000 numbers...Some ideas, I am thinking about automatise your method in Perl. Is another efficiently option? Thanks for your fast and accurate response.

Comment: stay in R ;-) may we see more of your data? you can paste the result of `dput(data[1:30,])` for instance.